# Restoring Ubuntu default icons folder

Tags: unity, themes, icons

Here's the stupid thing I did: I deleted many folders inside the icon folder, with root privileges, and now some icons are gone, but not the main ones, the ones from compiz for instance, or some from top notification bar, like the skype one. I looked for days to find a solution to restore the icons folder, or to find the default Ubuntu icons to put them back to the folder, but I have found none.

I use Ubuntu Tweak Tool to switch between themes, icons, or cursors, and it works perfectly, but no theme or icon pack seems to bring back some of the icons like I mentioned before.

I hope there is a way to reinstall ubuntu default icon packs. Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it: Downloaded the ubuntu 14.04 iso. Mounted it with VirtualBox, used root to go to the icons folder, archive it, uploaded it to the internet. Then downloaded it to my OS, and just copied it to the 'shared' folder. Basically I restored the icons folder by copying it from the ubuntu iso file. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, applications  like compiz usually install their own icons. You can install these icons by re-installing the application to replace the missing files.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall compizconfig-settings-manager
```

That should work if the files are missing, however, if it doesn't, you can download the application and manually replace the files like so:

```
cd
mkdir aptget;cd aptget
apt-get download compizconfig-settings-manager
ar xvf *
tar xvf data*
sudo cp -rT ./usr/share/ /usr/share/
cd ..
rm -R aptget
```

Comment: Can you please look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNS-1koj6TI&feature=youtu.be because it seems there might be more to this than just compiz icons, it seems that no matter what icon pack I select (ubuntu defaults or other that I installed) there are plenty of icons missing, but mainly small notification icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can download an unzip in the :
`/usr/share/icons`

download default icons from here:

http://4uploader.com/dl/257/icons.7z

Comment: Thank you very much. I did that but still it does not work. Here is the strange part - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNS-1koj6TI&feature=youtu.be as you can see there are icons missing no matter if I select an icon pack I installed or those original you sent me.